# SQLITE Error E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "monthly": syntax error

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Hi i've been getting a SQL error  that says 
 E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "monthly": syntax error

i believe it may have something todo with my create Table statement

```
  private static final String CREATE_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (" + UID +
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + POST_CODE + " VARCHAR(255)," + FIRST_LINE +
        " VARCHAR(255)," + TOWN + " VARCHAR(255)," + COUNTY + " VARCHAR(255)," + ROOM_NO +
        " INTEGER ," + ASKING_PRICE + " INTEGER ," + CURRENT_OFFER + " INTEGER ," + AGREED_PRICE +
        " INTEGER ," + AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," + AGENT_PHO_NUM + " VARCHAR(255)," + ESTATE_AGENT_NAME +
        " VARCHAR(255), " + REFURB_COST + " VARCHAR(255), " + TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT + " VARCHAR(255), "
        + DONE_UP_VALUE + " INTEGER ," +WEEKLY_ROOM_RATE+ " INTEGER ," +EXPECTED_RENT + " INTEGER ," + MAX_OFFER + " INTEGER ,"
        + DISCOUNT_PERCENT + " DECIMAL(3,2) ," + LOAN_TO_VALUE + " DECIMAL(3,2) ,"+ MORTGAGE_Interest + "DECIMAL(3,2) ," +
        MAX_MORTGAGE + " INTEGER ," + DESPOSIT_NEEDED + " INTEGER ," + DESPOSIT_REPAYMENT_MONTHLY+ " INTEGER ," + REPAYMENT_ANNAUL + " INTEGER ,"
        +STAMP_DUTY_PER + " DECIMAL(3,2) ," + STAMP_DUTY_ACT + " INTEGER ," +INSURENCES+ " INTEGER ," + TOTAL_PURCHASE_COSTS +
        " INTEGER ," + TOTAL_MONEY_NEEDED + " INTEGER ," + MORTGAGE_REPAYMENT + " INTEGER ," +
        BILLS_UTILS + " INTEGER ," + TOTAL_COST_PER_MONTH + " INTEGER ," + TOTAL_REFURB_COST + " INTEGER ," + TOTAL_PROJECT_COST +
        " INTEGER ,"+ TOTAL_PROFIT + " INTEGER ,"+ RENTAL_PROFIT + " INTEGER);";
```

this is my insertData method for adding to my database

```
public long insertData2(String posCode, String firstLine, String town, String county, int roomNum,
                       int askingPrice, int currentOffer, int agreedPrice, String agentName,
                       String agentPhone, String estateAgentNam, int refurb, String Time, int doneUp,int expectedRent
                        , int weeklyRent, int maxOffer,double discountPercent, double LoanToValue,Double mortgageInterest
                        , int maxMOrtgage , int despositNeeded, int despositRepayment, int despositRepaymentAnnual, double stampDutyPer,
                       int stampDutyAct , int insurances, int totalPurchaseCost,int moneyNeeded, int mortgageRepayments,int billsUtils,
                       int costPerMonth, int refurbCost , int projectCost, int totalProfit, int rentProfit) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(POST_CODE, posCode);
    contentValues.put(FIRST_LINE, firstLine);
    contentValues.put(TOWN, town);
    contentValues.put(COUNTY, county);
    contentValues.put(ROOM_NO, roomNum);
    contentValues.put(ASKING_PRICE, askingPrice);
    contentValues.put(CURRENT_OFFER, currentOffer);
    contentValues.put(AGREED_PRICE, agreedPrice);
    contentValues.put(AGENT_NAME, agentName);
    contentValues.put(AGENT_PHO_NUM, agentPhone);
    contentValues.put(ESTATE_AGENT_NAME, estateAgentNam);
    contentValues.put(REFURB_COST, refurb);
    contentValues.put(TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT, Time);
    contentValues.put(DONE_UP_VALUE,doneUp);
    contentValues.put(WEEKLY_ROOM_RATE,weeklyRent);
    contentValues.put(EXPECTED_RENT,expectedRent);
    contentValues.put(MAX_OFFER,maxOffer);
    contentValues.put(DISCOUNT_PERCENT,discountPercent);
    contentValues.put(LOAN_TO_VALUE,LoanToValue);
    contentValues.put(MORTGAGE_Interest,mortgageInterest);
    contentValues.put(MAX_MORTGAGE,maxMOrtgage);
    contentValues.put(DESPOSIT_NEEDED,despositNeeded);
    contentValues.put(DESPOSIT_REPAYMENT_MONTHLY,despositRepayment);
    contentValues.put(REPAYMENT_ANNAUL,despositRepaymentAnnual);
    contentValues.put(STAMP_DUTY_PER,stampDutyPer);
    contentValues.put(STAMP_DUTY_ACT,stampDutyAct);
    contentValues.put(INSURENCES,insurances);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_PURCHASE_COSTS,totalPurchaseCost);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_MONEY_NEEDED,moneyNeeded);
    contentValues.put(MORTGAGE_REPAYMENT,mortgageRepayments);
    contentValues.put(BILLS_UTILS,billsUtils);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_COST_PER_MONTH,costPerMonth);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_REFURB_COST,refurbCost);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_PROJECT_COST,projectCost);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_PROFIT,totalProfit);
    contentValues.put(RENTAL_PROFIT,rentProfit);




    long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);
    return id;


}
```

i've been looking at tutorials and checking online but i just can't seem to see where im going wrong can anyone please help?

UPDATE FULL error message

total refurb cost=0 Total Money Needed=1501 Insurences=1 Stamp duty actual=0 EstateAgentName=test rental profit=11 Mortgage Interest=1.0  AgreedPrice=0 AddressFirstLine=test  mortage Repayment=0 stamp duty percent=0.0 Total project cost=1503 AskingPrice=3000 total cost per month=1 max_offer=-24 RefurbCost=0 total profit=3565275 desposit needed=0 discount_percent=0.0 doneUpValue=3566778 county=test PostCode=test loan to value=1.0 NumberOfRooms=3 bills utils=1 Town=stevenage timeOfAppointment=27  AgentName=27 Max Mortgage=-24 Repayment Annual=0 Expected rent=12  AgentPhoneNumber=test

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "monthly": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Viewed(repayment monthly,CurrentOffer,Total Purchase costs,weekly room rate,total refurb cost,Total Money Needed,Insurences,Stamp duty actual,EstateAgentName,rental profit,Mortgage Interest, AgreedPrice,AddressFirstLine, mortage Repayment,stamp duty percent,Total project cost,AskingPrice,total cost per month,max_offer,RefurbCost,total profit,desposit needed,discount_percent,doneUpValue,county,PostCode,loan to value,NumberOfRooms,bills utils,Town,timeOfAppointment, AgentName,Max Mortgage,Repayment Annual,Expected rent, AgentPhoneNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: show string of CREATE_TABLE2  value

Comment: @PiotrGolinski Hi sorry im a bit new what do you mean?

Comment: If you add breakpoint at line where you use val 'CREATE_TABLE2 ' you'll can see how it look(at debug mode). Then paste it here

Comment: @PiotrGolinski Sorry to sound like a massive idiot but im still new to this and im not sure how to add a breakPoint im using android studio ,

Comment: 1. Find line 2. Click on left side, near line number 3. should be visible red dot 4 Click debug to start

Comment: @BeginnerJavaDev query seems fine. you should post your whole stacktrace or log

Comment: @MehulJoisar just edited my question

Comment: @MehulJoisar posted the full error code any idea?

Comment: @BeginnerJavaDev: Column name should not have space in its name because while querying it fails with syntax error. I guess this is where complexity occurs. Kindly change them and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you didn't construct your sql correctly which happens near "monthly" in your long string of concatenated elements.

There are so many wrongs in this sql:

```
INSERT INTO Viewed(repayment monthly,CurrentOffer,Total Purchase
costs,weekly room rate,total refurb cost,Total Money Needed, ...)
```

You are using spaces for column names.

I have two tips you can use to build easier sql.

1. First use a MySql client like Workbench to build your table more easily with the help of its GUI tools (but make sure the data types are compatible with Sqlite). When the query is about to be executed, you can see the raw sql which you can later copy-paste to your project.
2. Don't use String concatenation like that. Use `String.format`.

   ```
   String sql = String.format(
             "CREATE TABLE %s (%s,%s)",
             TABLE_NAME2,
             UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
             POST_CODE + " VARCHAR(255)");
   ```

Comment: any idea how i could fix this i have created a sql table 1 that works, and i tried to copy that process

Comment: This is like finding a needle in haystack. The problem is you are probably missing a ")"  or something like that in the string. However I have a couple of tips you can find useful. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I added the string format but i still get the error code( it doesn't crash my application though)

Comment: the same one as i posted early I've updated my question with  A a full error code :/

Comment: I think this is what you should do. Start with a very short sql like "INSERT INTO Viewed(repaymentmonthly) VALUES(?)" . If this works then add more and more. Remember that you cannot use whitespace in table or column name.